# Calculating the sum of numeric firebase records

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have managed to retrieve fire base data using the following code. I however would like to do more with the records that i just pulled.To be specific i want the total sum since they are numeric values..

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        //Getting the data from snapshot
        DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);

        //Adding it to a string


        String amount = "Amount: "+dogExpenditure.getAmount();


        expenseList.add(expenses);

            if (expenseList.size() == 1) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, expenseList);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else if (expenseList.size() > 1) {

            }
            System.out.println(expenses);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

My database looks like this[image]

so is possible to calculate the total of the two amounts??
My DogExpenditure class is:

```
**public class DogExpenditure {
    private String amount;
    private String item;

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}**
```

Comment: where is your DogExpenditure class?

Comment: i have edited my question @xFighter

Answer (score 0):

Declare amount(int) as global int variable in your activity and intitalize it to zero and replace 
 String amount = "Amount: "+dogExpenditure.getAmount();
with
amount+=amount+dogExpenditure.getAmount();
Notify me if this doesn't help

Comment: i get a null1200015000

Comment: Its clear form the output that while uploading amount for each key you are uploading its as string rather than number.Hence instead of being added the amounts are being concatinated.'0' is converted into string null too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class instead of the above one

public class DogExpenditure {

```
private int  amount;
private String item;

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

    //Getting the data from snapshot

    DogExpenditure dogExpenditure=postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);

    //Adding it to a string

    amount+=amount+dogExpenditure.getAmount();



    expenseList.add(expenses);

        if (expenseList.size() == 1) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, expenseList);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else if (expenseList.size() > 1) {

        }
        System.out.println(expenses);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}
```

}**

Also dont forget to initialize amount to 0 during beginning of activity and while uploading amount values to database via class make sure they are int.
Is this helping??